# Syntax error in LP Solve IDE trying to solve binary problem

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

[objective function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvbhZ.jpg)

whenever I run the program it gives me a syntax error in line 2 of the objective function (image attached)

I can't work out the reason for it

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a math question, but a programming syntax question.

Comment: Have you tried to replace the colon by an $\text{equality sign}$? If a syntax error is still reported then insert $\text{multiplication signs}$ between the coefficients and the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use expressions and parentheses in an LP format. I.e. instead of

```
0.02(x1 + x2)
```

you should use

```
0.02 x1 + 0.02 x2
```

Anyway, as always first read the documentation on the input format before guessing.